# Error with encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Code:

```
SELECT
       ta_name,
       countt,
       ta_unit,
       ta_id_producer_goods
FROM (
    SELECT  ta.name AS ta_name,
        ta.unit  AS ta_unit,
        ta.id_producer_goods AS ta_id_producer_goods,
        count(*) over(partition by ta.name) as countt,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ta.name order by getdate()) as r
    FROM  Table ta
    WHERE  id_city = '24'
       AND id_firm = '22131'
       AND id_service = '5'
) x
WHERE r=1
```

When I run the above query in SQL Server Management Studio, I get this result:

[image: screenshot]

Why do I get results in bad encoding and how do I get the right encoding ?

Comment: It depends of how the data is inserted.

Comment: I have many cases when data with one collation is inserted in table with different collation. I hope this is not your case.

Answer (score 1):

Manage your collation by:
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')

Comment: i get SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS what me need do with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the default collaction by:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')
```

Comment: i get SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS what me need do with it ?